# Create plots using python while separating excel data to new files

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, xlsxwriter

I'll preface this with the fact that I am new to Python and coding in general. I can successfully separate my data based on unique values in a certain column, but as the for loop iterates I also want to create a plot. For some reason, python is creating the separate Excel sheets but is completely ignoring the plot. Any advice/pointing out what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```py
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

excel_file = 'CR1000XSeries_LiftoffData.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name='CR1000XSeries_LiftoffData')

split_values = df['StrandID'].unique()

for value in split_values:
    df1 = df[df['StrandID'] == value]
    output_file_name = "StrandID" + str(value) + "Test.xlsx"

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output_file_name)
    ws = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet1')


    rows = len(df1)

    r1 = 1
    r2 = rows
    C1 = 0
    C2 = 9
    C3 = 14

    chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'scatter', 'subtype': 'straight'})

    chart.add_series({
        'categories': ['Sheet1', r1, C1, r2, C1],
        'values': ['Sheet1', r1, C2, r2, C2],
        'name': 'JackPressurePSI'})

    # Second Y axis
    chart.add_series({
        'categories': ['Sheet1', r1, C1, r2, C1],
        'values': ['Sheet1', r1, C3, r2, C3],
        'name': 'AbsoluteDispIN',
        'y2_axis': 1})

    ws.insert_chart('B10', chart)

    df1.to_excel(output_file_name, index=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that the program is overwriting the xlsx file created by `xlsxwriter.Workbook()` with one of same name created by `df1.to_excel()`.

See the XlsxWriter docs on [Working with Python Pandas and XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) for the correct way to use Pandas and XlsxWriter together.

Fixing that issue the program should work. Here is an updated version:

```
import pandas as pd

excel_file = 'CR1000XSeries_LiftoffData.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name='CR1000XSeries_LiftoffData')

split_values = df['StrandID'].unique()

for value in split_values:
    output_df = df[df['StrandID'] == value]
    output_file_name = "StrandID" + str(value) + "Test.xlsx"

    # Create a pandas excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_file_name, engine='xlsxwriter')
    output_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

    # Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

    max_row = df.shape[0]

    row1 = 1
    row2 = max_row
    col1 = 0
    col2 = 9
    col3 = 14

    chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'scatter', 'subtype': 'straight'})

    chart.add_series({
        'categories': ['Sheet1', row1, col1, row2, col1],
        'values': ['Sheet1', row1, col2, row2, col2],
        'name': 'JackPressurePSI'})

    # Second Y axis
    chart.add_series({
        'categories': ['Sheet1', row1, col1, row2, col1],
        'values': ['Sheet1', row1, col3, row2, col3],
        'name': 'AbsoluteDispIN',
        'y2_axis': True})

    worksheet.insert_chart('B10', chart)

    writer.save()
```

I couldn't test this fully because I don't have the input file but it compiles correctly. Also, I changed some of the variable names to make them more explicit.